# Play autoplay looping HTML5 video from start on click and then back to autoplay looping on pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

I have an autoplay looping HTML5 video that I need to play from the beginning of the video on first click and then when clicked again to pause have it go back to autoplay looping and then repeat those functions. Here is what I have so far

```
<video autoplay loop muted controls="false" poster="" preload="auto">
  <source src="promo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

$('video').click(function() {
  if (this.paused == false) {
      this.pause();
      $(this).removeAttr('controls');
  } else {
      this.play();
      $(this).attr('controls', true);
  }
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
$('video').click(function() {

    if (this.paused) 
    {
      this.play();
      // remove the attr's
      $(this).removeAttr('autoplay').removeAttr('loop');
    } 
    // If first time and is not paused 
    else if(!this.paused)
    {
      this.play();
      // add the attr's back
      $(this).('autoplay', 'autoplay').attr('loop', 'loop');
    }
});
```

Comment: I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" in console with this code. Also the code looks like it just removes and add attributes and doesn't play the video from the beginning.

Comment: Yes, I assumed you had the rest down your self? Would you like help with that too?

Comment: Apologies if that was not clear. I do not have the rest of the code. I would love help with that.

Comment: Well have to move it to a chat room

Comment: Actually I do have enough rep. Here is the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93106/video-help